# Unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ is a unitary operator, $A$ a vector self-adjoint operator and $v$ a fixed vector. Is it true that $U[v\cdot (U^\dagger A U)]^2U^\dagger$ equals to $(v\cdot A)^2$? I am mainly confused because of the dotting with $v$. Thank you.

---

For example, if it is simply $U[(U^\dagger A U)]^2U^\dagger$ then clearly this equals to $A$. but I don't understand how to deal with the $v\cdot$

---

Added Context: As Muphrid pointed out, "the linear operators act on functions, but the vector v belongs to a finite vector space (and hence, A is a vector of linear operators)".

Comment: How is $[v\cdot (U^\dagger A U)]^2$ to be understood?

Comment: How do you "dot" a vector with an operator?

Comment: This sounds like a quantum mechanics problem, where the linear operators act on functions, but the vector $v$ belongs to a finite vector space (and hence, $A$ is a vector of linear operators).  Is that similar to the context of the problem as you encountered it?

Comment: @Muphrid: Precisely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the context,the answer is *yes*.  Let's consider just one "component" of the full vector of operators.

$$U[v_x U^\dagger A_x U][v_x U^\dagger A_x U]U^\dagger = v_x^2 A_x^2$$

since you get a lot of $UU^\dagger$ or $U^\dagger U$ (which are all 1).  The logic extends to when the full vector of operators is considered, as the components of $v$ will commute with the operators because the vector is constant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for clarifying the context!